# Accessing NSTextField from its delegate notification…

Tags: delegates, nstextfield, nsnotifications

I'm subclassing `NSTextField`

**MultiTextField.h**

```
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>

@interface MultiTextField : NSTextField {
    id storedObject;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) id storedObject;
@end
```

**MultiTextField.m**

```
#import "MultiTextField.h"

@implementation MultiTextField
@synthesize storedObject;
@end
```

to store a pointer to an object, which I want to "rename".

I made this textfield editable and have a delegate which listens to `controlTextDidChange:` and works fine:

```
- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    NSTextView *textView = [[aNotification userInfo] objectForKey:@"NSFieldEditor"];
    NSString *theString = [[textView textStorage] string];

    if([theString length] > 0 ) {
        MyObject *theObject = ???; // I need access to the MultiTextField.storedObject!
        [theObject setName:theString];
    }
}
```

the only problem is that I can't access the storedObject (see comment in the if-block).

So how do I access that storedObject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
MyObject *theObject = [[aNotification object] storedObject];
```